# JQuery sortable only works on browser hard reload (meteor/blaze)

Tags: jquery, meteor, jquery-ui-sortable

I used Avital's example here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/examples/unfinished/reorderable-list

For some reason, in my implementation I need to reload the page to get it to work.  In other words, once my app loads in the browser, the list isn't sortable.  Then I refresh the browser page and everything is fine.

**My implementation:**

*On the client I call a server method to set the initial ranks for each item in the list.  Note, I also tried running the Meteor.call on the server inside Meteor.startup with the same result:*

```
Meteor.call("setInitialTodosRank")
```

*I add the sortable code (from Avital's example)*

```
UI.Body.Rendered = ->
        # uses the 'sortable' interaction from jquery ui
        $('.list-group').sortable stop: (event, ui) -> # fired when an item is dropped
            el = ui.item.get(0)
            before = ui.item.prev().get(0)
            after = ui.item.next().get(0)
            newRank = undefined
            unless before # moving to the top of the list
                newRank = SimpleRationalRanks.beforeFirst(UI.getElementData(after).rank)
            else unless after # moving to the bottom of the list
                newRank = SimpleRationalRanks.afterLast(UI.getElementData(before).rank)
            else
                newRank = SimpleRationalRanks.between(UI.getElementData(before).rank, UI.getElementData(after).rank)
            console.log "newrank is #{newRank}."
            Todos.update UI.getElementData(el)._id,
                $set:
                    rank: newRank
```

Packages used: Iron Router, jquery-ui-sortable, hammer, blaze-layout, and iron-router-active.

Comment: I removed Hammer and it works in a browser (ie. no refresh needed).  Must be a conflict with the libraries.  However, there is no touch solution for sortability I can find yet.  Looking for a new solution...